# Changing shape of Confetti canvas effect

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am looking to implement a Confetti effect for a landing page of the website and have stumbled upon perfect starter here: https://codepen.io/linrock/pen/Amdhr However, I need to edit shape of confetti to be small rectangles as opposed to circles:

I have tried changing:

```
context.arc(x,y,r,0,PI_2,false)
```

to

```
context.rect(10,10,10,20)
```

this results in one confetti on a page of shape that I want all of them to be, but as you will see gets rid of whole Confetti effect. I'm pretty sure that I need to edit `drawCircle` to achieve what I want.

Comment: You forgot to pass the dynamic x and y to the `rect` method: `context.rect(x, y, 10,20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
drawCircle = (x,y,r,style) ->
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(x,y,r,0,PI_2,false)
  context.fillStyle = style
  context.fill()
```

To

```
drawCircle = (x,y,r,style) ->
  context.fillStyle = style
  context.fillRect(x,y,r,r)
  context.fill()
```

**EDIT 1**

Please note that this is `CoffeeScript`, not `JavaScript`.

Comment: Looks good, any chance I can control the size of the rectangles?

Comment: the `r` variable in the `fillRect` function is `width` and `height` in that order. You could hardcode whatever you want into those fields like `context.fillRect(x,y,7,3)`